# Why svg "use" tag can not copy foreignobject?

Tags: html, svg

Why foreignObject does not appear in below situation?
Is that because "use" tag can not work for foreignObject element?

```html
<div>
  <svg id="test" width="200" height="100">
    <circle cx="150" cy="50" r="50" fill="red" />
    <foreignObject id="fo" style="width:100px; height: 100px">
      <div style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: grey">
        asdf
      </div>
    </foreignObject>
  </svg>

  <svg width="200" height="100">
      <use href="#test"></use>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: FWIW this works fine in Firefox, so that's most likely that Chrome didn't implement it.

Comment: Thanks, I tried in firefox it did works. seems like chrome's problem